# Are Progressive Web Apps a viable alternative to offline hybrid / native apps?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, offline

I have a hybrid app built in SAP Cloud Platform. This offline capability for situations where there is poor connectivity.

My question is could this have achieved through a Progressive Web App, and how?

Comment: Yes. You can learn more about PWAs here: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/